# Python and accessing command line utilities ifconfig, iwconfig and iw directly

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, ifconfig, iwconfig

I'm accessing ifconfig, iwconfig and iw from subprocess.Popen as below:

```
p = sp.Popen(["ifconfig",nic],stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()
```

Is there a better way, i.e faster to do this such as interfacing directly to the underlying code perhaps or is the added time delay negligible - time becomes a concern when using iw to switch channels.

Comment: if you're okay with external dependencies, native bindings exist (ie `python-ifconfig`).

Comment: I've looked at that however, it is my understanding that in the case of iw the "pythonic" version is very limited. How would one go about coding a python-iw with native bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally got around to writing own code - interfaces directly with netlink and ioctl to handle iw and ifconfig respectively - hosted on https://github.com/wraith-wireless/pyric and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRIC/

Answer (score 2):

Try reading/writing the relevant files from the [`/proc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux) filesystem directly.

The `/proc` pseudo filesystem is where the Linux kernel exposes a lot of information. You might want to look around in `/proc/net`, especially `/proc/net/dev` and `/proc/net/wireless`. See the [documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html), and some more [information](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-dir-net.html).

Comment: @dvp The `/proc` filesystem is where the Linux kernel makes a lot of information about processes and its internal state available for reading and sometimes writing. I've added some documentation links to my answer.

Comment: OK Thanks, what I've seen so far is good. Will this be the same across all linux?

Comment: @dvp Yes, basically. It is a filesystem made available by the kernel. The only way it wouldn't work is if the `/proc` filesystem isn't mounted. But a lot of tools depend on it, so it is generally always mounted. There are some differences in `/proc` layout between major kernel versions, though.